# How to export/extract audio from a DVD under Fedora 14?

Tags: fedora, dvd

i have a DVD's content on my HDD: i have these 2 usually folders, ok:

AUDIO_TS
VIDEO_TS

I just can't google a working way to extract the audio from the DVD. the howtos usually write about when the dvd is in the ODD. but i have it on my HDD, and don't want to burn it to a dvd (there are several dvd's exactly).
Are there any good way to extract the audio part from the DVD?

my original problem is that i want to convert them to h263 "AVI". But theres no sound when i open them with avidemux. but: i can import sound files to avidemux, if i had them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mplayer dvd://1 -dvd-device /path/to/copy_on_hdd/ -dumpaudio -dumpfile audio.ac3`

Comment: Error parsing option on the command line: -dvd-device=/path/to/copy_on_hdd/
MPlayer SVN-r31628-4.4.4 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team

Comment: Oh, it seems it should be without '=', but with space. I've updated answer

Comment: yep..i'm an idiot i didn't tried that one out.. :) THX!

Answer (score 0):

[K9Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy) is a powerful graphical tool that can read a VIDEO_TS directory structure (or a DVD) and produce (re-encode) MPEG-4 video files. It also supports MPEG-2 extraction, as well as Audio extraction, which is useful for creating lossless backups.

It is available in the Fedora repository. To install [K9Copy on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy), you need to enable the multiverse repository.